# Ruby on Rails. Can't create a record in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Having a problem while creating a new record in database.
Model currently looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

      before_save {!self.email.downcase}

      validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
      validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

      has_secure_password
      validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
end
```

Initially tried to create a record from the code, but failed without any errors.
As a next step I tried to create a record manually in console, but still with the same result. No errors available. Skipping validations, reseting database, restarting server or excluding email REGEXP (always a source of troubles for me) from validations doesn't help...

```
user = User.new(name: "Fedor U", email: "fredy@mail.ru", password: "asdzxc123", password_confirmation: "asdzxc123")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Fedor U", email: "fredy@mail.ru", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$89SABxu2lOo3gj6DiqLZEOlSheAfEk0ex.5GYmJ5e8i...">

>> user.save
(0.2ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('fredy@mail.ru') LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
>> user.errors.any?
=> false
user.errors.full_messages
=> []

>> user.save(validation: false)
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('fredy@mail.ru') LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Rails 4.2.0, bcrypt 3.1.7. 
Database is empty at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `before_save { self.email.downcase! }`?

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot! I'm an truly an idiot :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!self.email.downcase` will return `true` or `false`

use `self.email.downcase!` to change the email into smallcase.

Comment: God bless your sharp eyes! I looked at this code for hundred times, but haven't seen this obvious issue!!! Have to stop drinking vodka for breakfast :(